# Дописать начало и конец xml файла

Tags: c#, xml

Есть xml файл с циклической структурой вида

```
<Aaa>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
</Aaa>
```

Мне в начало этого xml надо дописать определенную (статичную) структуру и в конец закрывающийся тег. Либо наоборот копировать циклическую структуру в определенное место в статичном xml (между определенным тегом). Что можно использовать в данном случае и как лучше поступить? Те грубо говоря добавить "шапку" и конец.

UDP: Примерно вот так

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <F>
  </F>
  <E>
     вот сюда циклическую структуру
  </E>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как и с любым текстовым файлом, вам придётся читать файл построчно и записывать в новый файл.

Это в том удачном случае, если ваше изменение не затронет сути XML (например, не добавит новый namespace). В противном случае вам придётся десериализовать XML, изменить и сериализовать назад.

---

Для вашего случая скорее всего подойдёт такое:

```
File.WriteAllText("result.xml", preamble);
File.AppendAllText("result.xml", File.ReadAllText("source.xml"));
File.AppendAllText("result.xml", postamble);
```

где

```
var preamble = @"<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <F>
  </F>
  <E>";

var postamble = @"  </E>
</root>";
```

Comment: Сохранится ли структура xml? Можно на примере?

Comment: @e1s: Зависит от того, что именно вы хотите добавить. Дайте конкретный XML и конкретную добавку, которую вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Допустим корневой тег с атрибутами (схема и спецификация), потом два тега, допустим F и E, и в E надо скопировать эту циклическую структуру (допустим 3 итерации).

Comment: @e1s: Ну, тогда почему бы не просто построчно? Раз вы ничего не говорите про namespace'ы.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, namespace  в корневом есть же или вы не про это?

Comment: @e1s: Вопрос в том, не инвалидирует ли это внутренний XML. Если нет, можно не заморачиваться с десериализацией. По идее, если в существующем куске фрагмент без namespace'ов, то подойдёт.

Comment: Ну что вы мучаетесь? Сделайте нужную вам операцию в текстовом редакторе и посмотрите на результат! Если получилось нормально - значит, можно и построчно. Если получилась фигня - надо через DOM.

Comment: Нет схема одна, у меня затруднение как вставить в начало и конец по строкам, по сути в xml же одна строка.

Comment: @e1s: Подождите. У вас затруднение с чтением файла построчно или с записью в новый файл? «На месте» текстовые файлы не правятся, как известно.

Comment: @VladD есть два xml, можно на примере как сформировать искомый?